# Usage of <p> tags

Tags: html, css, semantics, paragraphs

As far as I know, `p` tags create paragraphs. But I often find HTML code where these tags are used for other aims. For example, I found it in a Codecademy exercise:

```
<div><p>Rex</p></div>

div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

It creates a circle with the name Rex in the center of this circle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvT6E. But the word Rex isn't a paragraph, it's just a word!

When I try to replace `p` tags by `span` (it seems more logical for me), it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/cvT6E/2/. Why not?

Finally, I would like to know:

1) Is the use of `p` tags semantically correct in the example?
2) Why isn't the word centred when `p` tags are replaced by `span` tags?

Comment: `span` is display inline, if you change it to display block it will work http://jsfiddle.net/cvT6E/3/ bottom line, if you don't want to use p then don't and use div or span. It could be a one word paragraph. Not everyone is going to follow semantics to the T

Comment: ***the world Rex isn't a paragraph, it's just a world*** confusing here.

Comment: p is a block element and holds phrasing content. span is inline-element and is part of phrasing content. Using a single span here would mean that if you  add text aside it into another span or not, they can be seen and read as a sentence. Wrap in ps, it is just single text outside other phrasing ccontent ... for single word , best is to use a list to my own opinion.

Comment: @user3546093 i guess worlds REX never existed, .. but age of dinosaurs ...

Comment: @user3546093 probably because your typo world = word

Comment: @Huangism, is p by default displayed block?

Comment: @Huangism I confused these words. :/

Comment: @user3546093 yes it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p first paragraph

Comment: `<table>` is supposed to hold a set of data, but people still use it for content layout all the time. Everyone has different standards when it comes to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

At first, recall that `<p>` is a block-level [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Mozilla puts it nicely "Their most significant characteristic is that they typically are formatted with a line break before and after the element (thereby creating a stand-alone block of content). That is, they take up the width of the containers." This explains why there `<p>` centers and `span` doesn't.

Furthermore, `<p>` is meant for paragraphs, so it is more appropriate for representing textual content, hence the semantic is preserved, as you might recognize too. I would suggest using `<span>` for situations where you do not have a semantic markup available in HTML, and in your case, representing a word or block of text with `<span>` is not insisted.

Appreciate that you might approach this with a different mindset, although I wouldn't recommend complicating things unless necessary. Observe the markup as stated below.

```
<p><span>text</span></p>
```

This would essentially give you the same effect i.e. centering of the "Rex" word in the circle, because `<p>` is a block-level element, and it can act as a container for the `<span>` element. Hence, the `<span>` would effectively inherit the properties of `<p>`
.This is evident from the fact that the text is vertically centered.

[image]

The `<span>` is on the contrary an inline-element, and think of it as a grouper, tying up elements together. Meanwhile, a `<div>` is an ideal container. Personally, I use `<span>` when I can't find an appropriate markup element and when I wan't no special properties of `<p>` or others. I like `<span>` for it's pureness.

If you strictly want to use `<span>` and center "Rex" in that circle, you can do this. The last two properties essentially enable you to do just that and the output is shown in the image below.

```
div span {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
        display:inline-block; 
        vertical-align:middle
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to write it : <div><span>Rex</span></div>. GCyrillus thinks in comments that I should create a list, maybe he is right. Thank for your answer.

Comment: It is an opinion, as there is no "recommended" solution as per the HTML specifications. Use what you feel will serve you in the long run.

Comment: ya this answer is way better than mine

Answer (score 1):

`p` is often used for displaying paragraphs, but it can also be used for many other things due to its default properties. In this case, span will not work because span has default `display:inline`.

Comment: And which tags I should use in my exemple? <span style="display: block"></span>?

Comment: or you can just use a div which is by default display:block.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 is primarily opinion-based, and the answers have no practical implications.

Question 2 has a simple answer: a `span` element is by definition an inline element (with `display: inline`), and the [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property thus does not apply to it (i.e., has no impact on its rendering). You can fix this e.g. by using `div` instead of `span` or by using `span` with the CSS declaration `display: block`.